# how to implement queuing system for customer service?

Tags: python

i want to implement a simple queuing system for customer service in python,and I'm confused between using Queue library(FIFO) or using data base (mysql for example),which of them is easy to implement,Thank you.

Comment: Could you be more specific to your requirements? Messaging/task queues are typically used for asynchronous transport and routing of messages for processing, whereas databases are typically used for long term storage of information.

Comment: a Queue from the library queue is indeed easier to use for any python program. But it does depend on the usecase. A python (memory) queue is only valid for the session / runtime. But with a SQL implementation it is persistent

Comment: queuing system for customer service (Bank for example),a simple easy queuring system ,the objectif is to Organize the queue of customers to pass through three windows.